# object loosing its managed object context

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a class in which I am insertingNewObject for some entity into managed object context. Managed Object Context is retrieved directly from the app's delegate and is a "strong" property as well.

Here is how I am creating the entity in parentViewController

```
_userPerformanceRecord = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"KRUserPerformance" inManagedObjectContext:[_gAppData managedObjectContext]];
```

Now according to my task, I have to pass this object to a new view controller, where I will do some changes into its values and then finally save it to database.

Now here is whats happening in the view's lifecycle methods.

```
init method
        NSLog(@"init : Object context for record %@", _userPerformanceRecord.managedObjectContext);

viewDidLoad
    NSLog(@"load : Object context for record %@", _userPerformanceRecord.managedObjectContext);

viewWillAppear
    NSLog(@"will appear : Object context for record %@", _userPerformanceRecord.managedObjectContext);

viewDidAppear
    NSLog(@"appear : Object context for record %@", _userPerformanceRecord.managedObjectContext);
    NSLog(@"Default Managed Object Context: %@",[_gAppData managedObjectContext]);
```

There is nothing else happening in these lifecycle methods, that will affect the this entity _userPerformanceRecord.

Output is as following

```
2014-09-04 13:46:01.957 myApp[5404:60b] init : Object context for record <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x15670eb0>
2014-09-04 13:46:01.958 myApp[5404:60b] <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x15670eb0>
2014-09-04 13:46:02.037 myApp[5404:60b] check perf : Object context for record <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x15670eb0>
2014-09-04 13:46:02.047 myApp[5404:60b] load : Object context for record <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x15670eb0>
2014-09-04 13:46:02.048 myApp[5404:60b] will appear : Object context for record <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x15670eb0>
2014-09-04 13:46:02.764 myApp[5404:60b] appear : Object context for record (null)
2014-09-04 13:46:02.764 myApp[5404:60b] Default Managed Object Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x15670eb0>
```

So now if you observe the output, you will find that entity's mananagedObjectContext exists till viewWillAppear but in viewDidAppear _userPerformanceRecord is loosing its managedObjectContext, but if I get the original managedObjectContext from app delegate, it still exists in memory, just the association of managedObjectContext with Entity is getting lost. I have no clue how through view's life cycle methods, objects managedObjectContext can get lost. Just to add, _userPerformanceRecord does still exist in memory after all this.

Comment: This happens when the object is deleted or removed from the context or store, but you are still retaining a reference to it.

Comment: It should not be deleted, there is nothing like deleteObject in there, plus why is it getting deleted between didAppear and willAppear is mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

> There is nothing else happening in these lifecycle methods, that will affect the this entity _userPerformanceRecord.

Maybe, but likely something else is happening to your managed object. I would recommend to also log the object itself (the managed object context is likely `nil` because the object is `nil`.

It could also have something to do with the way you set up the ivar. Try accessing `self.object` rather than `_object`. Please show the ivar declaration and state where you assign the object. The preferred place is `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Its not a storyboard based project, it has simple navigation controller and I am using pushViewController for the same, custom init method, passing the variable in function(Its an old project, hanging on since iOS 5). I checked _userPerformanceRecord, its not nil, its there in the memory. Plus how will it be different for accessing the property with _object or self.object when I have the memory for the object, but managed object context is not there. I will be using the Apple's tech support for this, almost tried everything.